# Do I need visa stopover 6 hour in Atlanta America,Tokyo japan

Tags: visas, transit

Do I need visa 6 hours stopover Atlanta America, and Tokyo japan and going to maynila ,
I'm Pilipino from Brazil what should I needed I only have passport and ticket only ..

Answer (score 1):

You do need a visa for the stop in Atlanta, as the airport has no international transit lounge (same as all USA airports).

You do not need a visa for Japan, as they do have an international transit areas for connecting passengers.